# VBA - Compile Error: Expected Function or Variable

Tags: vba, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a document that has an "invoice" number that increases on the document that goes up every time I print the document. I found a macro code online but I keep getting the

> Compile error

I'll attach a snap shot of what I'm getting with the piece that keeps screwing up highlighted.

```
Sub SerialNumber() 
'
' SerialNumber Macro 
'
'
Dim Message As String, Title As String, Default As String, NumCopies As Long 
Dim Rng1 As Range 

' Set prompt. 
Message = "Enter the number of copies that you want to print" 
' Set title. 
Title = "Print" 
' Set default. 
Default = "1" 

' Display message, title, and default value. 
Numcopies = Val(InputBox(Message, Title, Default)) 
SerialNumber = System.PrivateProfileString("C:\Users\JShewchuk\Documents\Macro\Settings.Txt", _
"MacroSettings", "SerialNumber") 

If SerialNumber = "" Then 
   SerialNumber = 0
End If 

Set Rngl = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SerialNumber").Range
Counter = 0

While Counter < NumCopies 
    Rng1.Delete 
    Rng1.Text = Format(SerialNumber, "00#")
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut
    SerialNumber = SerialNumber + 1 
    Counter = Counter + 1 
Wend 

'Save the next number back to the Settings.txt file ready for the next use.
System.PrivateProfileString("C:\Users\JShewchuk\Documents\Macro\Settings.Txt", "MacroSettings", _
        "SerialNumber") = SerialNumber 

'Recreate the bookmark ready for the next use. 
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks 
    .Add Name:="SerialNumber", Range:=Rng1
End With
```

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you are trying to assign a value to the sub iteself (as you would with a function)

Comment: I've edited your post to include the screenshot, but **please** in the future paste the **actual code** in your question (indented 4 spaces - from the VBE select the code, hit TAB, copy, then paste in your question)

Comment: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/NumberCopiesOf1Doc.htm

Answer (score 4):

To expand on [braX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48348085/1188513)...

That's the syntax for assigning the return value of a `Function` or `Property Get` member - namely, you are assigning to the procedure's identifier:

```
Public Function GetTotallyRandomNumber() As Long
    GetTotallyRandomNumber = 4
End Function
```

Seems you mean to have a local variable named `SerialNumber`, however VBA already knows this identifier as the name of a `Sub` procedure named `SerialNumber`, and because a `Sub` procedure doesn't return anything, it can't legally be assigned like this.

Declare a local variable inside the procedure's scope, before the illegal assignment:

```
Dim SerialNumber As String
SerialNumber = System.PrivateProfileString(...)
```

And then your code will work... however I wouldn't recommend using the exact same name as the procedure.

My recommendation would be to name the local variable `SerialNumber`, and to rename the `Sub` procedure so that its name starts with a verb. Procedures *do something*, they're *actions*: find a meaningful name that describes what it does, and go with that.

Naming is hard though - if you can't find a simple name that describes what your procedure does, it's probably because it's doing too many things. Split it up into smaller, more focused procedures.

```
Public Sub PrintActiveDocumentAndAddSerialNumberBookmark()
```

Comment: Great answer to a bad question IMO... This is related to this webpage, which needed this extra bit of code added! https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/NumberCopiesOf1Doc.htm

Answer (score 2):

You are treating a `Function` like a `Subroutine`. `Subroutines` do not return values.

If you want the routine to return a value, then change `Sub` to `Function` (at the top)

If you are not wanting it to return anything, then choose a different variable name instead of `SerialNumber`, or change the name of the `Subroutine`.

You cannot use a variable name that is the same as the name of the `Subroutine`.

Comment: *You cannot use a variable name that is the same as the name of the Subroutine* - actually VBA is pretty permissive with regards to member shadowing: you *can* declare a local `SerialNumber` variable within a `Sub SerialNumber` procedure's scope. Not that I'd recommend doing that though.